# Website stopped working with Chrome version 32

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome

I am the developer for a large enterprise website, after the upgrade to chrome 32 the website stopped working completely. I Get the 'aw snap' about the time we have to render most of the elements on the page.

Its a massive code base so i haven't been able to find what's causing it. Ive been booting chrome in debug mode and watching the logs there.

Wierd behavior:

1)If i disable flash it works, we are using swfobject with a flash library.

2)I sometimes see in the logs when it crashes "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" so i must have a infinite loop, but its not a always thing.

3)If i refresh enough it will boot all the way up, and work for good until i kill tab and start over. But again thats a sometimes cause it may start the crash cycle again after a few refreshes.

4) I sometimes see the error "file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors" Which i think relates to a infinite loop in the rendering of the webpage which would relate to the maximum call stack exceeded error.

Does anyone know what has changed in Chrome Version 32 that would be a good starting place to find the bug?

Libraries used: SWFobject, Backbone, underscore, soundmanager.js

Comment: Are you checking the site with `pepperflash` plugin switched on, or with native Flash?

Comment: Native Flash, but we tried both to make sure it wasnt pepperflash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know why this fixed it, or what chrome changed that caused the code to break but if anyone is interested in what we did to resolve the error i'll explain.

1) I made all events going out of swfobject and our swf code go directly to the Flash.js class we had to interface with flash. Before it was propagating through a Backbone.dispatcher to the flash class. That caused the aw snap error to go away.

2) We were using a datetime library called Moment.js version 2.2.0. It was the one throwing the maximum call stack error, after updating that to 2.3.0 it stopped. Would love to know what chrome changed to cause a infinite loop.

If anyone has info on what chrome changed between the two versions that caused either error, I would love the answer because its a bit scary fixing the symptoms but not knowing the cause.

Comment: Awesome find, thank you. I was searching for some acknowledgement so i could prove i wasnt crazy.

Comment: @Neablis you should mark your answer as 'correct' so others will know this question has been solved and does not need attention anymore.

Answer (score 1):

chrome will open multi tasks in the task manager, and it is sensitive to many plugins

try the following

1- go to settings in chrome
2- open extentions
3- disable all the extensions that you can
4- close chrome
5- open task manager in windows
6- go to processes
7- close all the processes related to chrome
8- reopen chrome and check your problem again

Comment: A lot of our testing is done on Mac but i understand your point. My testing environment has no extensions unlike my development environment. But thank you for the suggestion, it's always a good idea to approach a problem from a clean slate.